# I just need to cut an input per line. and then cut each line per word space in C# but I cant seem to figure out how 2d arrays work

Tags: c#, arrays

```
string[][] Chop = null;
string[] Line = null;



private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Line = textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None); // Im succesfull at cutting the input per line and stores it per line in Line variable.

    for(int x = 0;x < Line.Length; x++)
    Chop[][x] = Line[x].Split(' '); 

//I want the Chop to have an array of array of strings.
```

Answer (score 5):

So you want array of lines and for each line an array of words:

```
string[][] lineWords = textBox1.Text
            .Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
            .Select(l => l.Split())
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 for `Split()` without parameters - it will not remove empty words, but I forgot that it has default splitting by white space characters. Btw Split already returns an array

Comment: To remove the empty lines you could just change the 4th line to:
    .Select(l => l.Split().Where(w => w != String.Empty))

Comment: Although I would wonder at the advisability of introducing Lambdas and Linq when the question was over the use of jagged arrays. (there are only so many things you can learn at once)

Answer (score 3):

```
var lines = from line in text.Split(new [] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            select line.Split(new [] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

`lines` variable will be of type `IEnumerable<string[]>`.

If you need Arrays:

```
var lines = text.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(line => line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                .ToArray();
```

`lines` will be `string[][]`

*UPDATE* Also I think you can use property `Lines` of `TextBox` to get text splittes by lines:

```
var chop = textBox1.Lines
                   .Select(line => line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                   .ToArray();
```

Comment: it works! I dont really get it tho. Im new to c# and arrays give me a hard time. Thanks a lot:D

Comment: @user1548960 see also my remark on `Lines` property. It could be useful

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not certain what the exact question is, I do see a problem in the code that is at least related to the title, thus why this is an answer and not a comment.

Firstly, your working with jagged arrays (arrays of arrays), and not multi-dimentional arrays.

... Normally I would give a good description of jagged arrays, but a quick google will probably explain them better than I would, so instead I will end with this:
your last line of code should be

```
Chop[x] = Line[x].Split(' ');
```

Comment: I tried that before but that line gives me an Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error:( sorry if the question is not clear

Comment: you would also have to create the Chop array first, so before the loop, you would do

    Chop = new string[][Line.Length];